# Why does my code not display updated dates?

Tags: c++

Okay so what this program is supposed to do is display the date in M/D/Y format and for some unknown reason it always displays 1/1/1. I have been skimming through this the past 40 mins and still can't understand where I went wrong. Please help me out. Needmorewordstopostthissssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void displayDate();

class Date{
    public:
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;
        int mmax;
    
        //functions
            int getMonth();
            int getDay();
            int getYear();
            int setMonth();
            int setDay();
            int setYear();
};

int Date::setMonth(){
    int i;
    for (i=1; i!=0; i=1)
    {
        cout << "\n Input the month: ";
        cin >> month;
        if (month < 1) {
            cout << "Please input a valid month";
        }
        else if (month > 12){
            cout << "Please input a valid month";
            }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    return month;
}   

int Date::setDay(){
    int i;
    for (i=1; i!=0; i=1)
    {
        cout << "\n Input the day: ";
        cin >> day;
        if (day < 1) {
            cout << "Please input a valid day";
        }
        else if ((month == 1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 10 || 12) && (day > 31)){
            cout << "Please input a valid day";
        }
        else if ((month == 4 || 6 || 9 || 11) && (day > 30)){
            cout << "Please input a valid day";
        }
        else if ((month == 2) && (day > 28)){
            cout << "Please input a valid day";
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    return day;
}

int Date::setYear(){
    int i;
    for (i=1; i!=0; i=1)
    {
        cout << "\n Input the year: ";
        cin >> year;
        if (year < 1) {
            cout << "Please input a valid year";
        }
        else if (year > 2021){
            cout << "Please input a valid year";
            }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    return year;
}

int Date::getMonth(){
    int month;
    return month;
}

int Date::getDay(){
    int day;
    return day;
}

int Date::getYear(){
    int year;
    return year;
}

void displayDate(int d,int m, int y){
    cout << "Date: " <<m;
    cout << "/" <<d;
    cout << "/" <<y;
}


main(){
    Date x;
    int m,d,y;
    x.setMonth();
    x.setDay();
    x.setYear();
    m = x.getMonth();
    d = x.getDay();
    y = x.getYear();
    
    displayDate(d, m ,y);
}
```

Comment: 1/1/1 is in M/D/Y format

Comment: your getters returns local variables, not the one that is declared in class

Comment: After seeing your code, I assume that you are a beginner. Nothing bad, we all started as beginners. But you consistently use bad patterns here. I cannot imagine where `for (i=1; i!=0; i=1)` comes from, but it leads to an endless loop. If you use accessors (functions to read and set a member value), the member value should not be public. And the accessors should access the member value... `int Date::getMonth(){
    int month;
    return month;
}` returns the **local** uninitialized `month. My advice: find a C++ tutorial and reproduce it. Only then try to invent code...

Comment: My intend is not to be offensive. And I sincerely apologize if I was. But there are too many problems for a SO question here, so I do not even know how I could help you. Hence my advice to start from an example from a tuto (which you can expect to be correct) make some changes there and ask here as soon as it goes wrong. Then we (you and us) will focus on a single point and you will learn. If you do not, you will learn to use bad code and will never be a *good programmer*. Only a now old dinosaur opinion, forged from 40 years programming in various languages and systems...

Comment: @SergeBallesta that was supposed to be i++ i was probably zoning out from tiredness when I wrote that. I understand! I take no offense at all I will definitely take your adivce.

Comment: Consider using some kind of convention to distinguish member variables from locals - it can save a lot of pain. Eg, if `m_month` means the member, you'd never declare a local as `m_month` because the `m_` is only for members, and you can't accidentally confuse `month` with `m_month`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the getter is not returning the class member variables rather the local variables delared.

```
int Date::getMonth(){
    return month;
}

int Date::getDay(){
    return day;
}

int Date::getYear(){
    return year;
}
```

Make the getters like this to return the actual member value.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. I do have a question though, In my previous code it had the same structure except it worked as intended. Why is that?
double rectangle::getArea(){
 double area;
 area = length * width;
 return area;
}

double rectangle::getPerimeter(){
 double perimeter;
 perimeter = 2*(length + width);
 return perimeter;
}

Comment: @dbggad in that case you are calculating the area and assigning it to the local variable in the statement `area = length * width`, in this question the month, day and year is stored in member variables and hence that should be returned

Comment: Done! New to the site and didn't know much of how the stuff worked my bad. Also thanks for the extra answer, I understand much better now.

Answer (score 0):

```
int Date::getYear(){
    int year;
    return year;
}
```

In here, you declare a new `int year;` variable, that is not initialized, then you return that variable instead of the member variable of your class.

Change it to

```
int Date::getYear(){
    return year;
}
```

Similar for your other get() functions.

Your conditions are also not working as you want it to:

```
(month == 1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 10 || 12)
```

doesn't compare month to all those numbers, the numbers just all evaluate to true. The condtion should be:

```
(month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to fix a number of problems in your code. And I have added comments explaining why:

```
#include <iostream>

// using namespace std;    // avoid it if you can. It brings too many symbol in main workspace
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

void displayDate();

class Date{
    private:               // attributes should be private, only accessors should be public (encapsulation)
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;
        //int mmax;        // comment out member that the code does not (still) use

        //functions
    public:
        int getMonth();
        int getDay();
        int getYear();
        int readMonth();   // setMonth should be a setter: int setMonth(int month) { this->month = month;}
        int readDay();
        int readYear();
};

int Date::readMonth(){
    for (;;)        // idiomatic form for an endless loop
    {
        cout << "\n Input the month: ";
        cin >> month;
        if (month < 1) {
            cout << "Please input a valid month";
        }
        else if (month > 12){
            cout << "Please input a valid month";
            }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    return month;
}

int Date::readDay(){
    for (;;)
    {
        cout << "\n Input the day: ";
        cin >> day;
        if (day < 1) {
            cout << "Please input a valid day";
        }
        else if (day > 31){       // other conditions were useless
            cout << "Please input a valid day";
        }
        else if ((month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) && (day > 30)){ // fix
            cout << "Please input a valid day";
        }
        else if ((month == 2) && (day > 28)){
            cout << "Please input a valid day";
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    return day;
}

int Date::readYear(){
    for (;;)
    {
        cout << "\n Input the year: ";
        cin >> year;
        if (year < 1) {
            cout << "Please input a valid year";
        }
        else if (year > 2021){
            cout << "Please input a valid year";
            }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    return year;
}

int Date::getMonth(){
    //int month;       // the local variable would hide the member
    return month;
}

int Date::getDay(){
    //int day;
    return day;
}

int Date::getYear(){
    //int year;
    return year;
}

void displayDate(int d,int m, int y){
    cout << "Date: " <<m;
    cout << "/" <<d;
    cout << "/" <<y;
    cout << '\n';      // do not forget end of lines
}


int main(){      // main shall be declared to return int
    Date x;
    int m,d,y;
    x.readMonth();
    x.readDay();
    x.readYear();
    m = x.getMonth();
    d = x.getDay();
    y = x.getYear();

    displayDate(d, m ,y);

    return 0;    // better to be explicit
}
```

Other things could be improved, because re-usability is important in OOP. But I am too lazy to go further today ;-)